# iOS SDK: about using properties when creating objects programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, class, object

okay below is a standard example of creating a datepicker

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,250,100,100);

    UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];
    [myPicker release]; 
}

- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"value: %@",[sender date]);
}
```

this is all good and well.  I'm a little used to creating elements in IB so when I create an object programatically I'm not sure how to access the data.

What I mean is..  should I assign myPicker to a class property and then access it as _myPicker?

Or lets say I want to access the date inside of the pickerChanged method without calling another method.  Should I assign an NSDate property and re-assign it every time the picker is changed?

I ran into some memory issues when I was trying to do it that way. I had another method grabbing _theDate, and it probably tried to access it at the same time pickerChanged was modifying it?

Anyway, what I'm getting at is "whats the proper workflow when creating things like action sheets, and pickers programmatically".  When these things are changed, how should the resulting data be saved so the rest of the class can access it?

Bonus question:

Is there a difference between this?

```
for(UILabel *myLabel in view.subviews){
    NSLog(myLabel.text);
}
```

and this?  Do I need to check the class all the time if i know my view only contains a certain kind of object?

```
for((id) myLabel in view.subviews){
    if([myLabel isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]){
        UILabel *theLabel = myLabel;
        NSLog(myLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create a property for your picker: @property (strong,nonatomic) UIDatePicker *myPicker. Then when you create it, use self.myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init....]. When you want the date, just use self.myPicker.date

Comment: @hamobi Re your bonus question, if not all of the subviews were labels, you'd use the latter code sample. In fact, even if they were, I might still use that code, because if you add another control at some future date, you wouldn't want your code to break. The second code sample is more prudent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you will just define properties if you'll need to access them more than once. You can do this in the .m file's interface:

```
@interface MyObject()

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *myPicker;

@end
```

You will then be able to access it by either _myPicker or self.myPicker.

You shouldn't need another NSDate property in your class because you can access the set date at any time:

```
_myPicker.date
```

For your last question: the latter of the two is merely extra sanity checks. While you're writing your own code, and you *should* know what subviews you're adding in, it can't hurt to double check the type of the subviews incase anything should go wrong and you try to access selectors that don't exist. This is a larger programming question though and not necessarily objective-c or iOS specific.

Comment: While I stand by my observations about preferring `weak` over `strong` (because the view owns it, not the view controller), that's only applicable to ARC. In retrospect, I notice he's not using ARC, and `retain` is probably safest (and `nil` it in `viewDidUnload`, if supporting iOS versions prior to 6.0). But if using ARC, I'd prefer to create the control, add it to the view, and then assign it to a `weak` property, not a `strong` property.

Comment: Agreed, I just typed whatever was on my mind. I'll edit my answer to retain since he's not using ARC.

Comment: Actually, in retrospect, hamobi posted a non-ARC code sample, but then (in comment to other answer) says that he's using ARC and accidentally posted MRC code in his question. Unnecessarily confusing...

Comment: sorry guys!  i just copy and pasted that particular example.. i didnt catch it

Answer (score 0):

The documented approach is to intercept the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event, as per your example.

You would then typically copy the `[sender date]` value to a property in your `pickerChanged:` method.

If the user hits a save button, then the object that presented the view containing the picker should be able to retrieve the selected date via the property.

It's not considered good practice to use isKindOfClass:.  You should structure your code such that you always know what class you're dealing with.

Also, you should really switch to ARC so you don't need to worry about calling `release`

Comment: I'm on ARC.  i just copy pasted that particular example.  that's odd.  I wonder why I kept getting memory issues when I would re-assign _senderDate = [sender date] when the picker is changing.  I feel like it was re-assigning too much while something else was trying to access it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `UIDatePicker` property to hold one instance of your child controller

This is what you need to add in your `.h` file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *myPicker;
```

And then in your `.m` file you need to add a data source method for this date picker. something like what `rdelmar` has instructed above:

```
self.myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
```